# Call Javascript function using button OnClick event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have one button like

```
<asp:Button ID="btnfirstnext" TabIndex="1" runat="server" Text="Next" class="action-button" OnClick="btnfirstnext_Click" />
```

and I have javascript like

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        //jQuery time
        var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
        var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
        var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches


        $(".next1").click(function () {
            if (animating) return true;
            animating = true;

            current_fs = $(this).parent();
            next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

            //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
            $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

            //show the next fieldset
            next_fs.show();

            //hide the current fieldset with style
            current_fs.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
                step: function (now, mx) {
                    //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                    //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                    scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                    //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                    left = (now * 50) + "%";
                    //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                    opacity = 1 - now;
                    current_fs.css({ 'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')' });
                    next_fs.css({ 'left': left, 'opacity': opacity });
                },
                duration: 800,
                complete: function () {
                    current_fs.hide();
                    animating = false;
                },
                //this comes from the custom easing plugin
                easing: 'easeInOutBack'
              // $('btnfirstnext').trigger('click');

            });
        });
```

I want to call this javascript when I click on button 
please help me 
I have try like `OnClientClick="javascript: return .next1;"` but it not work and I also try `class=".next1 action-button"` with `onclicentclick="return false;"` and this is work but I don't want to use this because of some other problem .

Comment: Juat add class next1 in button and remove onclick event that js will run automatically as you already bind added on click function for next1 in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your button id match with the click event id name `next1` and remove `OnClick="btnfirstnext_Click"` from button

```
<asp:Button ID="next1" TabIndex="1" runat="server" Text="Next" class="action-button" />
```

and change your function parameter as bellow this will call this function

```
$("#next1").click(function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these solutions:

1) with function

```
<asp:Button TabIndex="1" runat="server" Text="Next" class="action-button" OnClick="javascript:doSomething()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
   //do something
}
</script>
```

2) with class (without dot before the class name in the button definition)

```
<asp:Button TabIndex="1" runat="server" Text="Next" class="action-button next" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".next").click(function() {
   //do something
});
</script>
```

3) with id

```
<asp:Button ID="next" TabIndex="1" runat="server" Text="Next" class="action-button" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#next").click(function() {
   //do something
});
</script>
```

Comment: no work any becouse i want to use onclick event also